# NodeJS - reading macOS .plist files

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

I have a `.plist` file on my mac that I would like to read. I can easily open it using Xcode but would like to do it using NodeJS.

I found `plist` package and I'm trying to use it like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import plist from 'plist';

fs.readFile('/my/path/here.plist', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  console.log('#data', data);
  const obj = plist.parse(data);
  console.log('#obj', obj);
});
```

What I'm getting as `data` is looking like this (a part from that file)

```
dataYdisplayasZfile-label]file-mod-date[arrangement_preferreditemsize��-   O(book(0$Usersnyc    Downloads �i(�   +� HXhA���L�  file:///Macintosh
```

`plist` package is throwing errors as I guess it expects string in `XML` format.

How can I read a `.plist` file like this?

Comment: Did you try to declare 'utf8' instead of 'utf-8'?

Comment: @Jayffe I found what was wrong - it was a binary file so I needed to find a way to convert it to plain `xml` :)

Answer (score 5):

I’d recommend using an appropriate library such as [bplist-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bplist-parser) (read-only) or [simple-plist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-plist) (read-write, wraps bplist-parser and bplist-creator, also handles plain text plist) instead of using the `child_process` module. Don’t forget that `exec` needs special care (e.g. arguments escaping) and it’s easy to shoot yourself in the foot using it!

```
import { parseFile } from 'bplist-parser';

parseFile('./path/to/binary/file.plist', callback);
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, found the solution. Guess posting to SO gives me more luck in googling...

macOS `.plist` files are mostly in binary. There is a command `plutil` that allows you to convert to binary to xml, so to do this in node you have to:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

const command = 'plutil -convert xml1 ./path/to/binary/file.plist';
exec(command, callback); // Here you gonna convert this file to plain `xml`.
```

Then you just have to repeat my steps from above - read the file using `fs.readFile` and then convert it using `plist` package so you get a nice JS object.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Consider using https://www.npmjs.com/package/plist MacOS